# flattern nested JSON and retain columns (or Panda json_normalize)

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a json with some nested/array items like the one below
I'm looking at flattening it before saving it into a csv

```
{'SKU':'TEST1','name':'test name 1',
    'ItemSalesPrices':[{'SourceNumber': 'OEM', 'AssetNumber': 'TEST1', 'UnitPrice': 1600}, {'SourceNumber': 'RRP', 'AssetNumber': 'TEST1', 'UnitPrice': 1500}],
    'ItemDiscounts':[{'SourceNumber': 'RETAIL', 'AssetNumber': 'AC', 'LineDiscountPercentage': 30}, {'SourceNumber': 'LARGE ACC', 'AssetNumber': 'AC', 'LineDiscountPercentage': 45}]
    },
{'SKU':'TEST2','name':'test name 2',
    'ItemSalesPrices':[{'SourceNumber': 'RRP', 'AssetNumber': 'TEST2', 'UnitPrice': 1500}],
    'ItemDiscounts':[{'SourceNumber': 'RETAIL', 'AssetNumber': 'AC', 'LineDiscountPercentage': 30}]
    }
```

I'm hoping to flatten it into more columns so when I save it to csv, it will still have 2 rows with set of columns representing the individual Source NUmber items in each array.

| SKU | Name | ItemSalesPrices_OEM | ItemSalesPrices_RRP | ItemDiscounts_Retail | ItemDiscounts_LARGE ACC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST1 | test name 1 | 1600 | 1500 | 30 | 45 |
| TEST2 | test name 2 |  | 1500 | 30 |  |

At the moment, why I'm doing is to go through each item, loop through the array and do all kinds of checking & comparing against the SourceNumber

I dont think I'm heading in the right direct and hope to hear from you guys to see how this should be tackled

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) or [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) and then join DataFrames by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
data = [{'SKU':'TEST1','name':'test name 1',
    'ItemSalesPrices':[{'SourceNumber': 'OEM', 'AssetNumber': 'TEST1', 'UnitPrice': 1600}, 
                       {'SourceNumber': 'RRP', 'AssetNumber': 'TEST1', 'UnitPrice': 1500}],
    'ItemDiscounts':[{'SourceNumber': 'RETAIL', 'AssetNumber': 'AC', 'LineDiscountPercentage': 30},
                     {'SourceNumber': 'LARGE ACC', 'AssetNumber': 'AC', 'LineDiscountPercentage': 45}]
    },
{'SKU':'TEST2','name':'test name 2',
    'ItemSalesPrices':[{'SourceNumber': 'RRP', 'AssetNumber': 'TEST2', 'UnitPrice': 1500}],
    'ItemDiscounts':[{'SourceNumber': 'RETAIL', 'AssetNumber': 'AC', 'LineDiscountPercentage': 30}]
    }]
```

---

```
first = ['SKU','name']
df1 = (pd.json_normalize(data,'ItemSalesPrices', first)
        .pivot_table(index=first, 
                     columns='SourceNumber', 
                     values='UnitPrice', 
                     aggfunc='sum')
        .add_prefix('ItemSalesPrices_'))
df2 = (pd.json_normalize(data,'ItemDiscounts', first)
        .pivot_table(index=first, 
                     columns='SourceNumber', 
                     values='LineDiscountPercentage', 
                     aggfunc='sum')
        .add_prefix('ItemSalesPrices_'))      
        
        
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
print (df3)
     SKU         name  ItemSalesPrices_OEM  ItemSalesPrices_RRP  \
0  TEST1  test name 1               1600.0               1500.0   
1  TEST2  test name 2                  NaN               1500.0   

   ItemSalesPrices_LARGE ACC  ItemSalesPrices_RETAIL  
0                       45.0                    30.0  
1                        NaN                    30.0
```

If no duplicates here is alternative solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

for x in data:
    for y in x['ItemSalesPrices']:
        d['ItemSalesPrices_' + y['SourceNumber']].update({(x['SKU'], x['name']):y['UnitPrice']})
    for y in x['ItemDiscounts']:
        d['ItemDiscounts_' + y['SourceNumber']].update({(x['SKU'], x['name']):y['LineDiscountPercentage']})

df = pd.DataFrame(d).rename_axis(['SKU','name']).reset_index()
print(df)
     SKU         name  ItemSalesPrices_OEM  ItemSalesPrices_RRP  \
0  TEST1  test name 1               1600.0                 1500   
1  TEST2  test name 2                  NaN                 1500   

   ItemDiscounts_RETAIL  ItemDiscounts_LARGE ACC  
0                    30                     45.0  
1                    30                      NaN
```

Comment: thank you. Couldn't figure out the pivot table approach and this is neat