# JSON list flatten to dataframe as multiple columns with prefix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a json with some nested/array items like the one below
I'm looking at flattening it before saving it into a csv

```
[{'SKU':'SKU1','name':'test name 1',
    'ItemSalesPrices':[{'SourceNumber': 'OEM', 'AssetNumber': 'TEST1A', 'UnitPrice': 1600}, {'SourceNumber': 'RRP', 'AssetNumber': 'TEST1B', 'UnitPrice': 1500}],
},
{'SKU':'SKU2','name':'test name 2',
    'ItemSalesPrices':[{'SourceNumber': 'RRP', 'AssetNumber': 'TEST2', 'UnitPrice': 1500}],
}
]
```

I have attempted with the good solution here [flattern nested JSON and retain columns (or Panda json_normalize)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73994722/flattern-nested-json-and-retain-columns-or-panda-json-normalize/73994803#73994803) but got no where so I'm hoping to get some tips from the community

| SKU | Name | ItemSalesPrices_OEM_UnitPrice | ItemSalesPrices_OEM_AssetNumber | ItemSalesPrices_RRP_UnitPrice | ItemSalesPrices_RRP_AssetNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SKU1 | test name 1 | 1600 | TEST1A | 1500 | TEST1B |
| SKU2 | test name 2 |  |  | 1500 | TEST2 |

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
first = ['SKU','name']
df = pd.json_normalize(L,'ItemSalesPrices', first)
print (df)
  SourceNumber AssetNumber  UnitPrice    SKU         name
0          OEM      TEST1A       1600  TEST1  test name 1
1          RRP      TEST1B       1500  TEST1  test name 1
2          RRP       TEST2       1500  TEST2  test name 2
```

Then you can pivoting values - if numeric use `sum`, if strings use `join`:

```
f = lambda x: x.sum() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else ','.join(x)


df1 = (df.pivot_table(index=first, 
                      columns='SourceNumber', 
                      aggfunc=f))
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')

df1 = df1.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
print (df1)
    SKU         name AssetNumber_OEM AssetNumber_RRP  UnitPrice_OEM  \
0  SKU1  test name 1          TEST1A          TEST1B         1600.0   
1  SKU2  test name 2             NaN           TEST2            NaN   

   UnitPrice_RRP  
0         1500.0  
1         1500.0
```

Comment: thank you for your help (you helped me in the other thread as well)
Yes I thought about the above, it would work but I'm wondering if there is another way if say we need to have 10 columns (with this approach, It looks like we will need 10 DFs?)

Comment: @Duyth - Solution was changed, can you test it?

Comment: this was exactly what I was looking for. thank you (I don't have enough rep to vote yet)